# How to map Source and destination using pattern in Auto mapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have different models in my N-Layered project which I want to map using Automapper.

I did as below

```
public ServicesProfile()
{
    CreateMap<State, StateModel>();
    CreateMap<StateModel, State>();
    CreateMap<City, CityModel>();
    CreateMap<CityModel, City>();
    //.... Some 100 models
}
```

Is there any simple approach to map by convention (ends with Model and remaining name same)?

Comment: You can omit CreateMap with newer versions.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu what do you mean by omit? Does it relate to my question or general suggestion?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Inline-Mapping.html

Comment: Of course creating maps on the fly can be misleading. A more explicit option is to use reflection to scan your types and create the needed maps using the non generic CreateMap overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Try u use

`CreateMap<State, StateModel>().ReverseMap();`

see: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/docs/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.md

Comment: Yeah, After a little bit of googling I am using this. But still looking if there is a better way